# Use Services in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am trying to make a REST request with angularjs.

Main.js

```
angular.module('frontendApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) 
  {

  $scope.loadData = function() {
     $scope.services = Services.query();

};
```

services.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('frontendApp').factory('Services', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/services/:serviceId', {
    serviceId: '@_id'
  }, {});
});
```

I get an error: Services is not defined. What did I wrong ?

EDIT:
Mains.html

```
<div class="jumbotron">


Choose A Category1
 <div class="wrap" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<select ng-model="selectedValue" ng-change="loadData()" >
  <option value="1">Category 1</option>
  <option value="2">Category 2</option>
  <option value="3">Category 3</option>
  <option value="4">Category 4</option>
  <option value="5">Category 5</option>
</select>



<div ng-show="selectedValue != null" class="main">
  <center><h2>Results For Category  {{ selectedValue }}</h2></center> <br><br>

</div>


<div  class="main"  >
  <ul class="cloudlist">
    <li class="service" ng-repeat="item in services" ng-click="select(item)">
      <div class="info">

        <h3>{{item.service_name}}</h3>
        <b>{{item.status_page}}</b><br>
        <b>Is Billed : {{item.is_billed.billing_term._identifier}}</b>


      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <br>
</div>

</div>
```

After injecting the Service in the controller

```
angular.module('frontendApp')
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'Services', function ($scope, $http, Services) {
        $scope.loadData = function () {
            $scope.services = Services.query();
        };
```

I get this error:
Unknown provider: ServicesProvider <- Services <- MainCtrl

Comment: did yo injected `ngResouce` module and its `angular-ng-resource.js ` like `angular.module('frontendApp',['ngResource'])`

Comment: Have you loaded your services.js file before loading main.js

Comment: I don't understand what do you exactly mean ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to inject Services in your controller.

```
var module = angular.module('frontendApp', ['ngResource']);

module.factory('MyServices', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/services/:serviceId', {
        serviceId: '@_id'
    }, {});
}]);

module.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','MyServices', function ($scope, $http, MyServices) {
    $scope.loadData = function () {
        $scope.services = MyServices.query();
    };
}]);
```

Comment: I have this error when I do it: Unknown provider: ServicesProvider <- Services <- MainCtrl

Comment: Error: Services is undefined
$scope.loadData@http://localhost:9000/scripts/controllers/main.js:13:13

Comment: you include the services.js before main.js in your HTML file?

Comment: I call services in main.js, I am not including anything, I added my html

Comment: try to change factory with service